# Android Menu onOptionsItemSelected styling menu items

Tags: android, android-menu, android-styles

I'm trying to **highlight menu item title** when it is **selected** in action bar and display its corresponding view in a fragment below. Fragment loading is working good but I'm not able to style menu items when they are clicked.

What I would like to have is something like below mentioned methods-

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
//     item.setSiblingsStyle(R.style.passive_menu_item);
//     item.setStyle(R.style.active_menu_item);
}
```

Is it possible to style menu title in "**onOptionsItemSelected**" method? Please help !

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use selector definition:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

     <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/blue_light"/> <!-- pressed -->
     <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="@color/grey_cloud"/> <!-- focused -->
     <item android:color="@color/black"/> <!-- default -->

  </selector>
```

Comment: can you elaborate ? I'm not sure how to use selectors in menu

Answer (score 1):

I've figured using just text is not a good way. So I decide to add icons and use state of items to toggle by maintaining few variables. Here is an implementation:

```
private current_selected_menu;
private main_menu;

public void updateMenuState(){
    if (main_menu==null){
        return;
    }
    int sz = main_menu.size();
    for(int i=0;i<sz;i++){
        if(main_menu.getItem(i).getItemId()==current_selected_menu){
            main_menu.getItem(i).setEnabled(false);
        }
        else{
            main_menu.getItem(i).setEnabled(true);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.sample_menu, menu);
    current_selected_menu = menu.getItem(0).getItemId(); // I'm using first item as enabled by default
    main_menu = menu;
    int sz = menu.size();
    for(int i=0;i<sz;i++){
        if(menu.getItem(i).getItemId()==current_selected_menu){
            menu.getItem(i).setEnabled(false);
        }
        else{
            menu.getItem(i).setEnabled(true);
        }
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.item1:
         // Do something
         current_selected_menu = item.getItemId();
         updateMenuState();
         return true;
    case R.id.item2:
         // Do something
         current_selected_menu = item.getItemId();
         updateMenuState();
         return true;
    default:
         // Do Something
         return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

As suggested by **Xingchen**, One can use selectors to define multiple icons. Below is a sample implementation:

**icon_selector.xml** file in **res/drawable**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_passive" android:state_enabled="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_active" android:state_enabled="true"/>
</selector>
```

**Note:** icon_passive.png and icon_active.png are two image files used as icons.

**sample_menu.xml** file in **res/menu**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/menu1" android:icon="@drawable/icon_selector" android:title="menu1" android:showAsAction="always|withText" android:visible="true"></item>
    <item android:id="@+id/menu2" android:icon="@drawable/icon_selector" android:title="menu2" android:showAsAction="always|withText" android:visible="true"></item>
    <item android:id="@+id/menu3" android:icon="@drawable/icon_selector" android:title="menu3" android:showAsAction="always|withText" android:visible="true"></item>
</menu>
```

I feel there could be better ways than above mentioned. I'll keep this open. Please feel free to suggest better solutions or better practices  : )